# Headless raspberry pi Selenium error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi, geckodriver

I'm trying running this code, it print **pretick**  but it never reach to print **tick**.

I'm getting this error after some time:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

This is the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument('-headless')

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1366, 768))
display.start()

print("pretick")
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(timeout=120)
print("tick")
```

And this is geckodriver.log

```
1519669744176   geckodriver     INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1519669744201   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:52201
1519669745835   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/fire$
1519669751870   Marionette      ERROR   Error on starting server: [Exception...$
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x804b0036 (NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADD$
MarionetteServer.prototype.start@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:95:19
MarionetteComponent.prototype.init@resource://gre/components/marionette.js:217:5
MarionetteComponent.prototype.handle@resource://gre/components/marionette.js:11$

1519670115749   geckodriver     INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1519670115787   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:55439
1519670117408   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/fire$
*************************
A coding exception was thrown and uncaught in a Task.

Full message: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Full stack:
*************************
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the complete error trace logs, as of now all the logs seems truncated.

Comment: I already pasted geckdriver.log entirely.